# How can you count, the amount of backtracks in Prolog SWI or CHR Prolog SWI

Tags: prolog, backtracking, swi-prolog, constraint-handling-rules

I'm creating several puzzle solvers in Prolog SWI  with CHR (Constraint Handling Rules)

Everything works great but, I like to test which solver is best one.
Therefore I like to find out, which solver uses the least amount of backtracks.

Is there a clever way to find out (or print out), the amount of backtracks that the solver had needed for solving a particular puzzle?

Logically, counting would help, but it doesn't --> backtracking ! <-- .
Also, printing a new line on the screen isn't effective, because of SWI's GUI. You can't print more than +/- 50 lines and can't select properly

Comment: gprofile could help you, browse the manual

Comment: gprofile? is it the same as profile/3?

Comment: profile/1, sorry I didn't remeber well

Comment: and this will return me the amount of backtracks? because that is what I need

Comment: should open a GUI where there are REDO count

Comment: It doesn't really satisfy my answer. Because the REDO isn't the amount of backtracks, but the amount of times that a clause executes something again.

Comment: You can take the number of inferences shown by statistics as a pretty good architecture independent and reproducible approximation for efficiency, should CPU-time be not good enough for you.

Comment: a REDO should happens just as a consequence of backtracking...

Comment: @Dieter when Prolog goes back to execute a clause again (REDO) to try to find another solution that's what backtracking is.

Comment: @Lurker, you're correct and not correct :) because of the reason that i'm using chr, i think that i've a lot of false calls and redo's for this reason.
But both, CapelliC and you, where helpful

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed not trivial to accomplish this, given Constraint Handling Rules maintain a 'constraint store' and execution of rules may **add**, **rewrite** or **remove** rules from this store at runtime. This changes the state of the program and makes it somewhat difficult to keep track of global states throughout execution.

However, since CHR is integrated in SWI, you can make use of the non-logical operation [nb_setarg/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=nb_setarg/3) to keep count of the backtracks.

Notes from the doc:

> - Compatible with GNU-Prolog's setarg(A,T,V,false)
> - This implementation is thread-safe, reentrant and capable of handling exceptions

**EDIT**

As regarding where to count the backtracks, this of course depends on your program, but will usually occur in the CHR constraint rule that defines the fail condition of your search, allowing it to 'branch' (= rewrite CHR rules). Every time a rewrite of the constraint store occurs during search, it represents a backtrack and you can increase a counter accordingly using the operation as defined above.

Consider a small, abstract example:

```
invalid_state ==> increment_backtracks, fail.
        guess <=> branch
```